# How to make gsutil rsync skip symlinks and return error code 0?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gsutil

I have noticed that when gsutil rsync is working, it will return a non-zero error code out if it encounters a symlink which it can not resolve:

```
$ gsutil -m rsync -r -C /my_folder/ gs://my_bucket/
CommandException: Error opening file "file:////my_folder/my_symlink": .
CommandException: 1 files/objects could not be copied/removed.
```

Is there any way I can exclude such symlinks during the sync and make gsutil return error code 0?

I do not know the names of the symlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [gsutil rsync documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) the `-e` parameter is used to ignore symbolic links.

Your command would look like:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r -C -e /my_folder/ gs://my_bucket/
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.